# freemarker and struts2 tags

Tags: struts2, freemarker

I am trying to use struts2 tags in freemarker template (jboss server).

Somewhere I saw that its simple, just instead of

Problem is that after trying to load my ftl with the code

```
<@s.form id="testId" namespace="/">
  <@s.select label="What's your favor search engine"
      name="roomModif[0].type"
      value="modifiedRooms[0].type"
      list="searchEngine" />
</@s.form>
```

i have exception

```
[FreemarkerTemplateEngine] Could not load the FreeMarker template named 'form':
[FreemarkerTemplateEngine] Attempted: /template/xhtml/form.ftl
[FreemarkerTemplateEngine] Attempted: /template/simple/form.ftl
[FreemarkerTemplateEngine] The TemplateLoader provided by the FreeMarker 
 Configuration was a: freemarker.cache.FileTemplateLoader
[ClosingUIBean] Could not open template
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Template /template/xhtml/form.ftl not found.
```

Can someone tell me what am i missing in my configuration?

Answer (score 1):

First steps:

Do you have **struts2-core.jar** in your war in Web-inf/lib?

If so, can you locate "*template/xhtml/form.ftl*" or "*template/simple/form.ftl*" in that jar?

If not, you have a problem with struts2-core library. Make sure you use the latest version of Struts2.